# Need to void Staging Server in Search Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web, search-engine

We have two server in .

1) Production Server
2) Staging Server

While googling i can find the Staging Server links are displayed in the search results. How to avoid the Staging links that are displayed in the seearch engine.

Thanks,
velu

Answer (score 1):

Here a [link](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) where the `robots.txt` is explained. You can prevent spidering your staging server by having such a file in you web root.